# Unable to perform validation inside a Jquery UI vertical tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, tabs

I am trying to perform simple validation on a form inside a Jquery tab. But when selecting the form with empty values the page simply refreshes but does not show the validations. Please let me know where it has gone wrong.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery- ui.css">
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
       <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>


    //Jquery script 

    <script>
    $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs().addClass( "ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix" );
    $( "#tabs li" ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-left" );
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();


    });




   </script>
     <script>
      $(function() {
      $("#register-form").validate({


        rules: {
            firstname: "required",
            lastname: "required",
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            agree: "required"
        },


        messages: {
            firstname: "Please enter your first name",
            lastname: "Please enter your last name",
            password: {
                required: "Please provide a password",
                minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
            },
            email: "Please enter a valid email address",
            agree: "Please accept our policy"
        },

        submitHandler: function(form) {
            form.submit();
        }
    });
      });
  </script>


      <style>
      .ui-tabs-vertical { width: 55em; }
        .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav { padding: .2em .1em .2em .2em; float: left; width: 12em; }
         .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li { clear: left; width: 100%; border-bottom-width: 1px !important; border-right-width: 0 !important; margin: 0 -1px .2em 0; }
        .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li a { display:block; }
         .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active { padding-bottom: 0; padding-   right: .1em; border-right-width: 1px; border-right-width: 1px; }
         .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-panel { padding: 1em; float: right; width: 40em;}
         .ui-widget {font-size: 1.1em;}
         </style>

       </head>


     <div id="tabs">
      <ul>

      <li><a href="#tabs-1">Guest</a></li>

       </ul>


        <div id="tabs-3"  >
        <h1>Register here</h1>

          <!--  The form that will be parsed by jQuery before submit  -->
         <form action="" method="post" id="register-form" novalidate="novalidate">

          <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" /><br />
           <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" /><br />
          <input type="text" id="email" name="email" /><br />
          <input type="password" id="password" name="password" /><br />
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></div>

        </form>


        </div>

       </div>

       </body>
       </html>
```

Comment: Can not reproduce the error. http://jsfiddle.net/1tvsxo76/ . Are there errors in browser console F12?

Comment: Hi Just tried with JSfiddle seems to work fine but when running it with Netbeans it does not display in chrome browser.Still looking into it.Thanks for letting me know there is no iusse with code.

Comment: So problem is not in jquery. Although what you can do is, hook an event on submit button and prevent default submit. Check if form is valid, submit the form. See the example in answer. probably this will prevent form submission interfered by something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extending example to my comment above.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("input[type='submit'][name='submit']").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
       var $regForm=  $("#register-form"); 
       $regForm.validate();

        if ($regForm.valid()) {
         $regForm.submit();
        }
    });
});
```